# Computing a decay rate for the Proca Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, scattering-cross-section

Consider a massive vector boson $V$ of mass $M$ interacting with fermions $f$ of mass $m$, where the Lagrangian is
$$
\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}M^{2}A_{\mu}A^{\mu}+g\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}A_{\mu}\psi
$$
so $A^{\mu}$ is the massive (real) vector field, and $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$ are the fermion and anti-fermion fields respectively, and $g$ is a real coupling. This leads to the decay $V(p)\to f(q)\bar{f}(q')$ (if $M>2m$). I'm trying to show that the differential decay rate for $V$ in its rest frame is given by
$$
\frac{d\Gamma}{d\cos\theta}=\frac{g^{2}M}{8\pi}\sqrt{1-\frac{4m^{2}}{M^{2}}}\left[1-\left(1-\frac{4m^{2}}{M^{2}}\right)\cos^{2}\theta\right]
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the 3-momentum $\underline{q}$ of $f$ and the polarisation vector $\underline{\epsilon}$ of $V$ in its rest frame. I'm using the normalisation for the polarisation vectors $\epsilon^{\mu}_{r}(\underline{p})\epsilon_{\mu,s}(\underline{p})=-\delta_{rs}$, and in the rest frame $p_{\mu}\epsilon_{r}^{\mu}(\underline{p})=0$.

So far, I have shown that the leading order amplitude for the decay is
$$
\mathcal{M}=ig\bar{u}(\underline{q},s)\gamma^{\mu}\epsilon_{\mu,r}(\underline{p})v(\underline{q}',s)
$$
where $\bar{u}$ and $v$ are the usual free-particle Dirac spinors. To get the decay rate, I (presumably) need to square this amplitude, and sum it over the spins of the final state fermions, and then use the standard formula
$$
\frac{d\Gamma}{d\Omega}=\frac{|\underline{q}|}{32\pi^{2}M^{2}}\overline{|\mathcal{M}|^{2}}
$$
Doing this, I've obtained
$$
\overline{|\mathcal{M}|^{2}}=g^{2}\text{Tr}\left[(\gamma^{\alpha}q_{\alpha}+m)\gamma^{\mu}\epsilon_{\mu,r}(\underline{p})(\gamma^{\beta}q'_{\beta}-m)\gamma^{\nu}\epsilon_{\nu,r}(\underline{p})\right]=4g^{2}\left(2(q\cdot\epsilon_{r}(\underline{p}))(q'\cdot\epsilon_{r}(\underline{p}))+q\cdot q'+m^{2}\right)
$$
using standard Dirac trace identities. However, it is here that I get stuck - I cannot see how to simplify this in such a way that I can get the correct result in the formula above. I would really appreciate any help in how to proceed here! If I've missed out any conventions/assumptions, please let me know. For full transparency, this is a past-paper question from the course I'm taking, and it has no solution anywhere - knowing how to finish it off would greatly help my revision!